# NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813) error

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, app-transport-security

I am facing the error while making HTTPS request :-

> **NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813).**

I did some google and there were some solutions mentioned to by pass the ATS (Application Transport Security) by mentioning the following key in my project info plist file. This is the issue in iOS9 and above.

> **Keys are :-
>
> key :- NSAppTransportSecurity
>
> value : -NSAllowsArbitraryLoads : true**

I have tried this solution. But i am still facing the same issue all the time. I am stuck in this. Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Apparently this is happening in ios version > 10. For fix it follow the next link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249559/react-native-xmlhttprequest-request-fails-if-ssl-https-certificate-is-not-vali

Answer (score 0):

You have to add just the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key to YES in NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in your info.plist file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Bhumika. But i have tried already this solution. It is not working.

Comment: It can be dangerous. Also Apple also says that using this solution will trigger app review [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW59)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue by implementing the authentication challenge delegate method of NSURLConnction.

Following implementation fixed my issue.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
       NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
      [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

      [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```